# react native i18next . change language between arabic and english

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native. I have this app that need to support Arabic and English. I use i18next for that. Arabic is right to left language so I need to change the styling of an app according to what language has been selected.

the problem start when I wanna change the language by what user chose the style will not change because the global styles will not refresh . global style file is like below:

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import i18next from "i18next";
import i18n from "./i18n";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./presentaion/components/context/AuthContext";

// let selectedLanguage = userLanguage<string | null>(null);

//check if it's arabic or english

const selectedLanguage = i18n.language;
export const globalPrimaryColor = "#F6C547";
export const globalsStyles = StyleSheet.create(
  selectedLanguage === "ar"
    ? //arabic styles
      { }
    : //english styles
      { },
);
```

the problem will solve if I make the app language depend on user phone language, But I want to make the user have the ability to chose the language he want without this styling problem.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have configure the library properly, you can switch language reactively by using this.

```
const ChangeLanguage = () => {

const { i18n } = useTransition()

const handleOnChangeLanguage = () => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(i18n.language === 'en' ? 'ar' : 'en')
}

return (
    <View>
        <YourUI></YourUI>
    </View>
)
```

}

Remember if you want your components to update the language immediately they must either get the locale with the HOC function **withTranslation** or the hook **useTranslation**. If you simply import the locale, you must restart the app.